# Issue dismissing/ re-presenting MFMessageComposeViewController with iOS6 but fine with iOS5

Tags: ios

I'm presenting an MFMessageComposeViewController which works fine with iOS4 and iOS 5 but has problems with iOS6.

The view is presented ok but if its dismissed and then represented it doesn't display correctly - only the To: line is displayed, the body and keyboard are missing. (Sorry I can't post a screen shot at the moment as XCode crashes when I take a shot, I'm downloading an older version of XCode as I type).

Stepping through the code in the debugger I noticed that the problem may originate earlier than the re-presenting - I noticed than when dismissViewControllerAnimated: gets called the entire view does not get dismissed immediately, rather it is the message body and keyboard that gets dismissed leaving behind the To:, the same thing that is displayed when the view is re-presented.

It might be easier to describe with screenshot, I'll post some shortly.

I'm using presentViewController: and dismissViewControllerAnimated: to  present/dismiss the MFMessageComposeViewController.

+++ UPDATE +++
I've found the problem can be solved if instead of using the same MFMessageComposeViewController object to re-present the view I first delete it and then create a new one.
That seems a little inefficient though, and it should not be necessary I'd have though, like i mentioned it worked on iOS5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS 6 apple introduced a new feature "remote view controller". Some external view controllers are no longer part of your app, and the messaging controller is one of them.

I guess that is the problem in your case.

you can read more about it there: http://oleb.net/blog/2012/10/remote-view-controllers-in-ios-6/